# getElementsByClassName and change class of each one consecutively

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I'm using a RSS to Javascript converter so I get about 15 items with the same class and I want to change each of those for an individual class.

something like this.

```
getElementsByClassName('genericclass')class = ("one")
if("one") "alreadytaken" else ("two")
if("two") "alreadytaken" else ("three)
```

I Hope you get the idea, and probably it's easier using random class selector right?

---

This is one jQuery way to do this, I cant manage to change the classes from the div generated by the other javascript.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/rrmonn/7tRMS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
var classes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('genericclass');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].className = classes[i]
}
```

using jQuery

```
var classes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
$('.genericclass').removeClass().addClass(function(i){
    return classes[i]
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nje2n/)

Comment: This Helped a lot but just with the regular classes but not with the ones generated by the other javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.genericclass').each(function(i){
   $(this).addClass('customClass_' + i);
});
```

Comment: Love this simple solution ;) +1

Comment: Only issue is, OP is using text not numbers, but it is the simplest and most logical solution. +1 hoping OP knows how to create the relevant CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use smt like that:

```
$('.genericclass').each(function(index,item){
  $(item).attr('id', $(item).attr('id') + '_' + index);
});
```

it is not gonna working if you are not using jQuery.
I hope is has helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script mentioned [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm) to convert number to word. And then you can use the following code -

```
$.each($(".genericclass"), function(i, v){
    i = i+1;
    $(this).addClass(toWords(i));
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2XPs/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
(function() {
    var i, classes;
    classes = document.querySelectorAll('.genericclass');
    for(i=0; i<classes.length; i++) {
        classes[i].className = 'newclass' + i;
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
jQuery(function () {
var classes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
$('.rssincl-itemimage').removeClass().addClass(function (i) {
    return classes[i]
})})},150);
```

Adding setTimeout for the other javascript to load the classes and then this script changes evryt